# How to extract data from Minecraft .mca files

Tags: c++, minecraft

I would like to generate a map for my own world, so I wrote a program try to analyze data from files in C++.
According to [this page](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Region_file_format), the region file begins with a 4KB head which tells the positions of each chunk.
I wrote a program, but it outputs the wrong stuff.

This is my program

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
char DataRaw[4100];
uint8_t DataUnsigned8[4100];
struct F4K{int pos,sz,dfn;} _chunk[40][40];
int main()
{
    ifstream file("first4K.sample",ios::binary|ios::in|ios::ate);
    ifstream::pos_type n=file.tellg();
    freopen("offset.out","w",stdout);
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read((char*)(&DataRaw),n);
    DataRaw[n]='\0';
    file.close();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        DataUnsigned8[i+1]=uint8_t(DataRaw[i]);
    for (int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<32;j++)
        {
            int id=4*((i&31)+(j&31)*32);
            _chunk[i][j].pos=(DataUnsigned8[id+1]<<16)|(DataUnsigned8[id+2]<<8)|(DataUnsigned8[id+3]);
            _chunk[i][j].sz=DataUnsigned8[id+4];
        }
    }
    cout<<" X  Z   offset  sz\n-------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<32;j++)
            cout<<setw(2)<<i<<setw(3)<<j<<setw(9)<<_chunk[i][j].pos<<setw(4)<<_chunk[i][j].sz<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it outputs this

```
 X  Z   offset  sz
-------------------
 0  0  2098751  32
 0  1  2098252   2
 0  2   139296  73
 0  3  2113312  32
 0  4   286978  32
 0  5  2099058   3
 0  6  2098275   2
 0  7   139271  65
      ...
31 25  7602464  32
31 26  2556192   1
31 27  2105407  32
31 28  6546821 168
31 29 10927590 179
31 30 15109023  35
31 31 15315359 230
```

I expect that the offset is sorted and begins with `8192`,but it was totally wrong! Some addressed (for example X:31,Y:31) is even bigger than the file size (The size is only `8,048,640` Bytes)
May anyone tell me why?

Comment: This question might be better off on other stackexchange communities, gamedev for example. As I understand it, the question isn't really about a code issue but about minecraft specific file formats.